# Set seed on Math.random()

Tags: java, random, random-seed

I need to write some junit tests on Java code that calls `Math.random()`.  I know that I can set the seed if I was instantiating my own Random object to produce repeatable results. Is there a way to do this also for `Math.random()` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method `Math.random()` uses a private static field:

```
private static Random randomNumberGenerator;
```

If you *really really* need to set this to a `new Random(CONSTANT_SEED)` (for instance you need to JUNit test code which you have no control over) you could do so by using **reflection**.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on the reflection part of your answer please?

Comment: As of Java 8 (or maybe it was always like this) this is hidden slightly further away - there is a private static final `RandomNumberGeneratorHolder` class in Math that then holds a static final `Random`.

Answer (score 9):

How about creating an instance of `Random` yourself and using that instead? `Math.random()` creates one and uses that, so I don't think that you can mess with its seed. If you create a `Random` and use it directly, however, you can set the seed for that when you create it, and/or you can call `setSeed()` on it later.

Answer (score 3):

Set it with instance of Random with your seed or just extend the methods to return values you need

```
        Field field = Math.class.getDeclaredField("randomNumberGenerator");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(null, new Random() {

            @Override
            public double nextDouble() {
                return 1;
            }

        });
```

Comment: The canonical version of random should return 4!